# How to delete all records from multiple tables with VBA loop? Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want a VBA loop function that will delete all records from any table with a name like "d2s_*".

I've found code to delete all records:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM NameOfTable"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

I've also found a loop to call each table in the database:

```
Dim T As TableDef
For Each T In CurrentDb.TableDefs
Debug.Print T.Name
Next T
```

So what I want to do is combine them:

```
Dim T As TableDef
For Each T In CurrentDb.TableDefs
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM NameOfTable"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
Next T
```

But as I understand, the SQL query has to reference a specific table name.  Is there a way to make this relative to any table starting with the name "d2s_"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim T As TableDef
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
For Each T In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If T.Name Like "d2s_*" Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM " & T.Name
    End If
Next T
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```