# How to delete contents of mulitple tables in Microsoft Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax, vba

I need to clear the contents of multiple tables in an Access db using VBA.

Below is the code I am attempting to use, but it throws a "Syntax error in FROM clause." The SQL syntax (`DELETE * FROM [table name];`) works in a query.

```
Dim tbl As TableDef
Dim sqlstr As String
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

For Each tbl In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If tbl.Name Like "*_drop" Then
        sqlstr = "DELETE * FROM " & tbl.Name
        DoCmd.RunSQL sqlstr
    End If
Next tbl
```

I found a similar problem and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530274/how-to-delete-all-records-from-multiple-tables-with-vba-loop-access-2010), but it did not solve my problem.

I have also tried it without the sqlstr and received the same error.

```
For Each tbl In CurrentDb.TableDefs
    If tbl.Name Like "*_drop" Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM " & tbl.Name
    End If
Next tbl
```

Comment: I found the issue. Mods can delete this question as the resolution is unrelated to the stated problem.

While debugging I found the VBA module would fail at the fifth table every time. The problem was some of the table names had an "&" character which caused the SQL string to read incorrectly.

Comment: Most VBA developers will tell you that table and field names should **never** contain spaces or anything other than strict alphanumeric (0-9 and A-Z) characters.  I can't tell you how many headaches I've had because databases I've inherited didn't follow those simple rules.  Conversely, I can't tell you how many times I've looked like a genius to my bosses because my stuff works while other coders have problem after problem because they don't follow those simple rules.  :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You confirmed a query like this works without error.

```sql
DELETE * FROM [table name];
```

However the query your code builds does not bracket `table name`.  Therefore, any table name which includes a space or contains nearly any character other than letters, digits, and underscore will result in a `DELETE` statement which triggers that error.  If the table name matches a reserved word, that could also trigger the error.  (Unfortunately it's difficult to predict exactly when reserved words will cause trouble.)  It's safer to bracket all troublesome words in queries when they are used as field or table names.  And for those which are troublesome because they are reserved words, you can alias them instead of bracketing.

But wherever practical, the *safest* practice is to rename all such objects: avoid reserved words; and use only letters, digits, and underscore.

Meanwhile, code defensively to cope with problem names. Revise the code to always bracket the table name.

```vb
sqlstr = "DELETE FROM [" & tbl.Name & "]"
```

Comment: +1 because you're right.  But, better yet, never put spaces in your field and table names!  ;o)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need `DELETE FROM` without the *

Comment: I believe Mike is saying I should try: DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM " & tbl.Name -- omitting the "*" in the SQL string.  Either way, the SQL should work.  I tried both with and without.

Comment: Access will gladly execute either `DELETE FROM` or `DELETE * FROM`.  If you want to preview the affected records in Datasheet View from the query designer, you must include `*` so that Access knows which columns to display.